# Follow up question on getting multi line string given search string

Tags: bash

I need an enhancement to the solution for this topic: [How do I get multi-line string between two braces containing a specific search string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588469/how-do-i-get-multi-line-string-between-two-braces-containing-a-specific-search-s)

The solution is working if the search string is inside the bracket:

```
awk -v RS='[^\n]*{|}' 'RT ~ /{/{p=RT} /test/{print p $0 RT}' file
```

where:
`/test/` - find test inside the bracket

I'm trying to change or manipulate the `'RT ~ /{/{p=RT} /test/{print p $0 RT}'` part but to no avail

From a file contaning:

```
blabla
program1 {
  blabla
}
blabla
program2 {
  blabla
  blablaeventblabla
}
```

Instead of searching for the value inside the bracket, I want to check or return the whole block by searching "program2". So the awk will return

```
program2 {
  blabla
  blablaeventblabla
}
```

Comment: You did find similar question (well done), but should post your case as a stand-alone qustion (referring to the old question that doesn't work for you). Perhaps you can explain more: are you searching for a `programx()` and can you have nested semicolons ? Show wat is wrong with the `sed -n '/program2 {/,/^}/p'`

Comment: Use a parser for that programming language