# sed remove section between curly braces

Tags: sed

I'm trying to delete a section elasticsearch { * } from a configuration file due to lack other options.

```
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
        }
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["{{elasticsearch/host}}:{{elasticsearch/port}}"]
          template_overwrite => true
       } 
  }
 }
}
```

I tried to reverse the sed command found on stackoverflow but it deletes ending } from configuration files too.

```
[root@indexer conf.d]# sed '/{/{:1; /}/!{N; b1}; /elasticsearch/!p}; d' example              
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
```

It may be due to }} in to cfg that must be there. Any ideas to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance

Edit:

some other experiment:

```
sed '/elasticsearch {/{:1; /}/!{N; b1} }; /elasticsearch/!p; d' example 
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
        }
                  template_overwrite => true
            } 
           }
  }
}
```

But leaves template_overwrite and some closing braces.

Comment: Where did you pick up the `sed` command you use? It simply gobbles up things within curlies and prints only if the collected fragment doesn't contain `elasticsearch`. There is no attempt to preserve the closing curly; in fact, you could argue that it strives to remove the closing curlies. It was probably posted in response to a question about extracting information from within the innermost set of curlies in a structure ...?

Comment: In here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32588469/how-do-i-get-multi-line-string-between-two-braces-containing-a-specific-search-s . I tried experimenting a little bit, unfortunately I am no sed wizz, only can write some simple commands...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*elasticsearch {$/{:a;N;/^\s*}$/M!ba;d}' file
```

Gather up the lines beginning `elasticsearch {` and ending `}` and delete them.

N.B. This uses the `M` flag for a multiline match for the end condition which is GNU sed specific. An alternative:

```
sed -n '/^\s*elasticsearch {$/{:a;n;/^\s*}$/!ba;d};p' file
```

Comment: 1st solution works for me, I only added [[:blank:]]* between elasticsearch string and opening brace in case there is > 1 space. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    RS="^$"                            # read in the whole file
    c=1                                # brace counter
}
{
    match($0,/\n? *elasticsearch \{/)  # find the start of string to remove
    print substr($0,1,RSTART-1)        # RUNNING OUT OF BATTERY
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    while(c>0) {
        match($0,/(\{|\} *\n*)/)
        if(substr($0,RSTART,1)=="{")
            c++
        else
            c--
        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    print
}' file
```

Output:

```
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
        }
  }
 }
}
```

Only tested with provided data.

Comment: This works for me too as well as this sed solution. I picked sed as it is used in script but I'm generally impressed with this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ sed '/elasticsearch[[:space:]]*{/,/^[[:space:]]*}/d' file
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
        }
  }
 }
}
```

The above will work with any POSIX sed. If that's not all you need then please edit your question to show a more truly representative example so we can help you. FWIW I wouldn't really do the above as it's not extensible if/when your requirements vary slightly, I'd do this instead:

```
$ awk '/elasticsearch[[:space:]]*{/{f=1} !f; /^[[:space:]]*}/{f=0}' file
output {
  if [env] {
      if [containerimage] and [containerimage] != "apache" {
        file {
          path => "/var/log/logstash/logs/%{[env]}/%{file}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}"
        }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, those two work for me as well and they a bit less complicated to the eye than from previous answer. All I wanted to remove elasticsearch sections surrounded by curly braces, that's all. But thanks for providing another point of view with awk, I'll see into that.